# CLI console command: "dotnet run --project" NuGet unauthorized error (401)

Tags: .net, package, nuget, authorization

this command `dotnet run --project` throws an unauthorized result, previously it worked fine, I had no issues with it. I don't know how can I pass the nuGet authorization arguments within this command `dotnet run --project myProjectXYZ` to make it work again.

The error is:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.101\NuGet.targets(156,5): error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). [C:..XYZ.csproj]

The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.
```

In Rider or VS the code runs without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Just open again this project you want to run in the IDE (such as Rider or Visual Studio) and go to:

`Tools -> NuGet -> NuGet Force Restore`

(remember to be logged to your nuget provider, but as you said there everything works fine, then you're logged correctly)

After this simple few clicks, you can again run
`dotnet run --project`